# Typescript Generator Property / Getter

Tags: typescript, properties, generator, getter

Making a generator method in typescript is simple:

```
class Foo {
    *values() { yield 10 }
}
```

But I want to make a generator *property*, something like this:

```
class Foo {
    get *values() { yield 10 }
}
```

But that seems to be invalid. I can't seem to find any references to this question or workarounds (aside from the obvious of using Object.defineProperty explicitly, which would suck because it would be untyped). Am I missing something? Is this supported? If not, will it be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could fake it with a backing method.

```
class Gen {
    private *_values() {
        yield 3;
        yield 4;
    }

    public get values() {
        return this._values();
    }
}

let g = new Gen();

let v1 = g.values;
let v2 = g.values;

console.log(v1.next());
console.log(v1.next());
console.log(v1.next());
console.log(v2.next());
console.log(v2.next());
console.log(v2.next());

/* stdout
{ value: 3, done: false }
{ value: 4, done: false }
{ value: undefined, done: true }
{ value: 3, done: false }
{ value: 4, done: false }
{ value: undefined, done: true }
*/
```

Comment: If only there were generator lambdas, this would be so much nicer.